# I can't move element a lastposition and first position

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, element, move

My list of countries I can't move item current and last position and firs position. But move element down and up position is correct.

My HTML:

```
<div class="ListCountries">
  <div class="item">Argentina</div>
  <div class="item">Bolivia</div>
  <div class="item">Brasil</div>
  <div class="item">Chile</div>
  <div class="item">Colombia</div>
  <div class="item">Ecuador</div>
  <div class="item">Paraguay</div>
  <div class="item">Peru</div>
  <div class="item">Uruguay</div>
  <div class="item">Venezuela</div>
</div>
```

My Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(".item").append("<p><button class='down'>down↓</button><button class='up'>up↑</button><button class='first'>Move First</button><button class='last'>Move last</button></p>");

$(document).on("click",".up",function() {
    var ob = $(this).closest('.item');
    ob.insertBefore(ob.prev());
});

$(document).on("click",".down",function() {
    var ob = $(this).closest('.item');
    ob.insertAfter(ob.next());
});

$(document).on("click",".first",function() {
    var ob = $(this).closest('.item');
    ob.insertAfter(ob.prepend());
});

$(document).on("click",".last",function() {
    var ob = $(this).closest('.item');
    ob.insertAfter(ob.append());
});
```

My jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cds0f5yp/20/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @RobinZigmond OP is asking why the "move first" and "move last" buttons don't work as intended.

Comment: missed that, thanks @ChrisG

Comment: This does it: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/5koysrqw/

Comment: @Chris G thanks a lot, but I have a small problem. I can not do it dynamically with multiple listsCountries. not mixing both lists.

You:

https://jsfiddle.net/uvzq8cmw/2/

My:
https://jsfiddle.net/uvzq8cmw/4/

Comment: Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/2jdzu98c/ (and you for some reason went back to `insertBefore` in "move last")

Comment: @Chris G, Now if everything works, very friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".item").append("<p><button class='down'>down↓</button><button class='up'>up↑</button><button class='first'>Move First</button><button class='last'>Move last</button></p>");

$(document).on("click",".up",function() {
    var ob = $(this).closest('.item');
    ob.insertBefore(ob.prev());
});

$(document).on("click",".down",function() {
    var ob = $(this).closest('.item');
    ob.insertAfter(ob.next());
});

$(document).on("click",".first",function() {
    var ob = $(this).closest('.item');
    ob.parent().prepend(ob);
});

$(document).on("click",".last",function() {
    var ob = $(this).closest('.item');
    ob.parent().append(ob);
});
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/jr63cuw7/)

Comment: thanks, your solution is better, working in multiple Lists-Countries no mixing both list. :)

Comment: @RenatoRamosPuma :)

Answer (score 1):

i used [.prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) and [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) on the item passing as target his parent to achieve what you are looking for. Here's my code for move first / last.

```
$(document).on("click",".first",function() {
    var ob = $(this).closest('.item');
    ob.prependTo(ob.parent());
});

$(document).on("click",".last",function() {
    var ob = $(this).closest('.item');
    ob.appendTo(ob.parent());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following change is working fine for me:

```
$(document).on("click",".first",function() {
    var ob = $(this).closest('.item');
    ob.insertBefore($(".item").first());
});

$(document).on("click",".last",function() {
    var ob = $(this).closest('.item');
    ob.insertAfter($(".item").last());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use correct selector to correct target.

```
$(document).on("click",".first",function() {
    var ob = $(this).closest('.item');
    ob.insertBefore($('.item:first'));
});

$(document).on("click",".last",function() {
    var ob = $(this).closest('.item');
    ob.insertAfter($('.item:last'));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/taegqpk8/

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is:

- move first: [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to your **ListCountries**
- move last: [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to  your **ListCountries**

  $(document).on("click",".first",function() {
      // move at beginning
      var ob = $(this).closest('.ListCountries');
      ob.prepend($(this).closest('.item'));
  });

  $(document).on("click",".last",function() {
      // move at end
      var ob = $(this).closest('.ListCountries');
      ob.append($(this).closest('.item'));
  });

```js
$(".item").append("<p><button class='down'>down↓</button><button class='up'>up↑</button><button class='first'>Move First</button><button class='last'>Move last</button></p>");

$(document).on("click",".up",function() {
    var ob = $(this).closest('.item');
    ob.insertBefore(ob.prev());
});

$(document).on("click",".down",function() {
    var ob = $(this).closest('.item');
    ob.insertAfter(ob.next());
});

$(document).on("click",".first",function() {
    var ob = $(this).closest('.ListCountries');
    ob.prepend($(this).closest('.item'));
});

$(document).on("click",".last",function() {
    var ob = $(this).closest('.ListCountries');
    ob.append($(this).closest('.item'));
});
```

```css
.item{
    width: 400px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #FFEEAA;
    border: 2px dotted Orange;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ListCountries">
    <div class="item">Argentina</div>
    <div class="item">Bolivia</div>
    <div class="item">Brasil</div>
    <div class="item">Chile</div>
    <div class="item">Colombia</div>
    <div class="item">Ecuador</div>
    <div class="item">Paraguay</div>
    <div class="item">Peru</div>
    <div class="item">Uruguay</div>
    <div class="item">Venezuela</div>
</div>
```